# Twilio javascript client has no audio

Tags: javascript, audio, client, twilio

I tried using the Twilio Javascript Client Quickstart and am having some audio issues. I am trying to place a call to a cell phone from the browser. In general, everything seems to work without errors. The issue I am having seems to be an audio problem.

Edge - The call goes through, I can hear the audio from the microphone on the client but I cannot hear the audio from the phone on the client.

Chrome - I cannot even get the call to connect because I cannot click the Call button. It seems to get hung up on the microphone permission.

Firefox - The call goes though but no audio on either end.

IE - The Call button and textbox too enter in the phone number on the client don't even display.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!!

EDIT: Based on the comments I tried to use the sample files without changing them. There were some errors and I had to add the bootstrap and modernizr packages in nuget. Same result. No audio.

Comment: I've used the client quickstart before and didn't have these issues. Can you tell me which version of the Twilio client JS you are using? And have you changed any of the code? One thing to start is that IE doesn't support WebRTC, which is behind Twilio Client, so that will not work.

Comment: You can also use https://networktest.twilio.com/ as a way to test your browsers readyness.

Comment: I have not changed the code but I have integrated it into a new project.. The version is 5.9.0. I understand regarding IE, thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem in Chrome browser, but it works in Firefox, I have no ideas why ... Did you found out the issue? thx.

Comment: I'm sorry, this was so long ago I don't remember. Good luck!